# Bevel Modifier Amount Conistency

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bevel

Is it possible to get a consistent result from the amount of bevel on different "complex objects"?. Example below: 2 objects with identical modifiers and applied scale display much different results per the bevel amount. Would like to get the same symmetrical bevel result on every object regardless of shape or size. Thanks for any assistance.

[image]

Comment: `Clamp Overlap` will prevent all the bevels from growing bigger than the smallest once possible. When a bevel runs into other geometry it will stop growing. Try turning that off and see your results.

Comment: Ahh, thank you!